# How do I restrict the number of records to be processed in an SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a table with 7M records I want to trim down to 10k for dev.  I tried a delete, but the whole world was nearly overpowered by the transaction log size, so I truncated the table.

Now I wish to insert 10k records from the original table, into my dev table, but it has a identity column, and many, many other columns, so I'd thought I'd try SSIS (through the wizard), which handles the identity nicely, but gives me no place to edit a query.  So I quickly made a view with a top clause, and changed the RowSet property of the source to the view.  Now everything fails because nothing sees the view, although I copied and pasted the view name from my create view statement, which fails a second time because, lo, the view actually does exist.

Does SSIS define which DB objects are used when a package is created, which would exclude the new view, and if so, how can I refresh that?

Comment: Do the 7 million records represent transactions?  If so, it may make sense to identify a 1000 or so recent customers and then only take their transactions from each table.  If you use random records, then you may only get old style records and incomplete customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no need to use SSIS to do this.  You should be able to insert the records using SQL.  First, you will need to set IDENTITY_INSERT to on.  Then, you should be able to execute something like this:

SET IDENTITY_INSERT db.schema.dev_table ON

INSERT INTO dev_table SELECT TOP (10000) * FROM prod_table

Comment: My problem here is listing all the fields.  I probably could have found a way of scripting them, but was in a hurry to get started and thought SSIS would offer a nice, quick, convenient way.

Answer (score 1):

Ed is correct, SSIS is overkill for this task - especially as you are only inserting 10K records.

Assuming the DEV table's schema is identical to the production, the script Ed displayed will work just fine.

If the schema is different, you can specify the columns specifically - including the identity column (remembering to set the identity insert OFF afterwards). For example:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.dev_table ON
INSERT INTO dev_table (Id, Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4)
SELECT TOP 10000 Id, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 FROM prod_table
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.dev_table OFF
```

Comment: This solution seems to assume Dev and Prod are either on the same server, a linked server has been setup between Dev and Prod, or a temporary database has been created on Prod that will be populated and moved to Dev, or a copy of Prod has been restored to Dev.  Good solution if 4th is true.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have used the row sampling control to extract a random number of records from the overall data rather than just getting the top 10000 rows.  This would give a better sampling for use in development/testing since you would not be developing against only your 10000 oldest (if your distribution is like most tables I have seen) records, but instead a sampling from across your entire file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try closing and reopening the package?  I wouldn't expect you to have to do this though.  My first thought would be it is a security issue - that you haven't granted yourself select on it.

Comment: I went back to the wizard (a longish back an forth process), and redid it with a query to select top 10k, instead of just copying a table.  I must still check how the second package differs from the first.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the fully qualified name to the view?  Doe sit have a different owner than the default owner?  OPen up the data source and do a preview of the data to make sure it's all hooked up.